# add to a string variable without deleting last assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
strings = None
def test(a)

       strings = str(strings) +  f"{a} \n"
```

when this function is called multiple times

```
test("hello")
test("world")
```

how do I allow strings to be equal to

```
"hello" \n
"world"
```

At the moment it just picks up the last time a was passed so strings is "world"

Comment: Do you mean to concatenate with `repr` or what? Why not pass `strings` in as an argument and `append()` to it?

Comment: I just want the variable strings to show all hello world in above example but world on a new line. I want strings to capture all the different a parameters been used.

Comment: `strings += str(strings) +  f"{a} \n"`. `+=` works as concatenation for strings.

Comment: The way you've described it is with quotes around the strings. What does that mean?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. The result you describe won't happen with the code you show (after fixing the obvious syntax errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None cannot be concatenated with a String, Also `strings` is a global object and needs to be so declared or a local object will assigned within the function. Try:

```
    strings = ""
    
    def test(a):
        global strings
        strings  +=  f"{a} \n"
    
    test("hello")
    test("world")
    
    print(strings)
```

Comment: `strings +=` is the same as `strings = strings +` in the OP's code. How does this help?

Comment: issue seemed to do with assigning strings to None at start. Issue resolved.

Comment: You should explain the problems you're fixing in the answer, not just post code.

Comment: @Barmar: a good point; answer edited.